# Get rid of App Namebar in IntelliJ

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I want to remove (or hide) the upper name bar that is generated in IntelliJ for android application .... in eclipse it would be if I am not mistaken would be by editing in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

is it the same for IntelliJ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume its the same for IntelliJ. I use Android Studio which is built off of IntelliJ and android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this has broken recently (at least in Intellij).  Choosing one of the NoTitle themes will crash the app when you run because the theme needs to be a descendant of AppCompat (at least for lower minimum SDK versions), but it seems there isn't one currently that hides the titlebars.

Here is a working fix for hiding the title bar in both your running app as well as in the layout preview:

1) Set your theme back to 'AppTheme' in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

2) Update the theme style in res/values/styles.xml by adding (to name="AppTheme"):

```
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

I believe you can also do this with 'android:windowFullscreen' if you also want to hide the action bar.

The above two steps will work when you run the app (emulator or device) but the layout will still show the titlebar.  You can hide that for working on your layout by going to the layout (such as activity_main.xml) and then clicking on the theme (AppTheme) above the preview and changing it to something like Light.NoTitleBar.  It's unfortunate that the preview ignores the theme changes in styles.xml, but hopefully that will get fixed.